# Make array lookup efficient in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova

I am working on a `phonegap` application where we fetch rss feeds and convert it to json and save it to local storage on in ".json" file.
The json data file contains few arrays, which stores 500 to 1000 elements normally.
For processing and rendering data on screen I often have to lookup for the matching elemenst in arrays and it is coded like:

```
for each array in arrys
    for each element in array
        if element.id=idToLookUp
            //do something
```

As this type of iteration is used heavily in app its little slow.
How can I optimize this process by using efficient data structures in `JavaScript`.
Can I use some third arty libraries like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) etc considering the app is built in PhoneGap and runs on decenly powered smartphones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object as a lookup table. Example:

```
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  loopup[array[i].id] = array[i];
}
```

Then you can get the item using the id:

```
var item = lookup[idToLookUp];
```

Comment: when I do lookUp[800]=someItem; only, what will be memory eaten by arra/ array.Length? 800 or 1?

Comment: @user2139676: Those are stored as descrete properties in the object, so it's only the actual items that use memory. The number of properties are just the ones that you store in the object, it won't add more properties to fill the gaps.